# Python making GUI windows

Tags: python, user-interface

I wrote a program that makes 3 things which user may choose:

```
def createLeague(): #creates a list with all teams
   file = open('league1.txt', 'r')
   teams = []
   for line in file:
      team = line.split()
      teams.append(team)
   file.close()
   return teams

def getTeam(teams): #this function gets a team that user inputs
   result = ' '
   choice = input('Enter the team: ')
   checkforteam = False 
   for line in teams:
        team = line[0] 
        if choice == team: #check for input team in all lines
           result = team               
           games = line[1]
           wins = line[2]     #assign all statistics to the variables with
           draws = line[3]    #appropriate names
           loses = line[4]
           checkforteam = True
   if checkforteam: #if it is True, it will return the team. If False, returns an error message
      print(result, games, wins, draws, loses)
   else:
      print('No such a team')

def getWinner(teams): #returns a leader
     winner = ' '
     result = 0
     loses = 100
     for team in teams:
         points = int(team[2])*3 + int(team[3])
         lose = int(team[4])#counting all points
         if points > result: #find a team with maximum points
            result = points
            winner = team[0]
            loses = lose 
         elif points == result:
            if lose < loses:
                winner = team[0]

print('Winner: ', winner)
print('Points: ', result)

def updateScore(teams): #update the table
    firsteam = input('Home: ')
    secondteam = input('Away: ')
    goal1 = int(input('Goals scored by home: '))
    goal2 = int(input('Goals scored by away: '))
    f = open('nhl.txt', 'w')
    for team in teams:
        komanda = team[0]
        matches = int(team[1])
        wins = int(team[2])
        draws = int(team[3])
        loses = int(team[4])
        if firsteam == komanda:
            if goal1 > goal2:
               matches += 1
               wins += 1
            elif goal1 == goal2:
               matches += 1
               draws += 1
            else:
               matches += 1
               loses += 1
        elif secondteam == komanda:
            if goal1 < goal2:
               matches += 1
               wins += 1
            elif goal1 == goal2:
               matches += 1
               draws += 1
            else:
               matches += 1
               loses += 1

        newline = komanda+ ' '+ str(matches) + ' ' +str(wins)+ ' '+    str(draws) + ' '+ str(loses)+ '\n'
        f.write(newline)
 f.close()
 print('Saved')


 teams = createLeague()

 loop = 1 #variable that makes 'while' working until user wants to close the program
 while loop == 1:
    print('0. Exit')
    print('1. Find a team')
    print('2. Get a leader')
    print('3. Update the results')
    x = input('Choose: ')
    if x == '1':
        getTeam(teams)
    elif x == '2':
        getWinner(teams)
    elif x == '3':
        updateScore(teams)
    elif x == '0':
        print('Goodbye!')
        loop = 0
    else:
        print('Wrong!')
```

Now I want that when I choose 1, 2 or 3 in IDLE, there will be a GUI window appeared where the function that called in while loop will work. I am stucked about it. How I can do it? Please, just show an example for one of the function.

Comment: You could try learning about `tkinter`. It's what IDLE uses.

Comment: I learned tkinter and tried to write a window, but it didn't work totally. Unless I would not ask help here.

Comment: You should probably tell us what was the problem with `tkinter`, otherwise the only answer you're gonna get here is do it with `tkinter`

Comment: The problem is not about tkinter, I mean I could not make input variable in GUI to search or update(as shown in my code) in GUI. Just advice how I should do it may be enough but make a GUI window for one of three functions and explain will be fine.

Comment: Who cares about all your menu options and game statistics? If you need a pop-up dialog that asks a question and lets you type in the answer, say so and show what you tried that didn't work (using as simple an input/output task as possible).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow by the way. Please not that on this site, you're expected to help yourself as far as you can, and help others help you.